# C++ vector of pointer to object - max_size()

Tags: c++, vector, max-size

I have a class apples

```
class apples
{
  private:
      double x;
      double y;
      double z;
  public:
      //some methods
};
```

I want to store the pointer to **apples** objects in a vector.
I am doing this so that i create any object in any file & use any object in any file.
I used the following code to determine the max no of pointers i can store in that vector

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
vector<apples *> myvector;
cout<<"max :"<<myvector.max_size();
return 0;
}
```

it gave me:

```
1073741823
```

now, my question is that can i really store 1073741823 no of pointers in that vector or is this the memory limitation (i.e. 1073741823 bytes) of the vector?

so if there are 2 vectors

```
vector<int> A
& 
vector<double> B
```

can A have 1073741823 elements & B also have 1073741823 elements?
i am asking this to clarify that,
 **the max no of elements that a vector can store does not depend on the the type of entity (int or double) being stored?**
(this has nothing to do with the current capacity of the vector!)
Also, what would be the size of a pointer to apples object (not asking the size of apples object!)?
Thank You.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is library limitation for storing elements in a vector.

[`vector::max_size()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/max_size/) :

> Returns the maximum number of elements that the vector container can
>   hold.
>
> This is not the amount of storage space currently allocated to the
>   vector (this can be obtained with member vector::capacity), but the
>   maximum potential size the vector could reach due to system or library
>   implementation limitations.

So, you can not store more than it (*and in practice maybe less than it due to system limitations)*

In other words even if you have best resource (memory, CPU, ...) abilities and your elements have minimum size, you can not store more than `max_size()`

*And according to the comment on `max_size()` in the  header file: Returns the size of the largest possible %vector.*

Comment: so does that mean, vector<int> or vector<double> can have 1073741823 elements, despite the difference in memory size of int & double?

Comment: If you have enough memory yes. but, `vector<double>` will allocate memory more that `vector<int>`.

Answer (score 4):

`max_size` returns an upper bound on the number of elements the vector can hold. This doesn't mean that `v.resize(v.max_size())` will succeeds. It merely means that `v.resize(v.max_size() + 1)` will fail.

Comment: Provided that `v.max_size() + 1` doesn't overflow, of course.  (The overflow would introduce undefined behavior before the call to `v.resize()`.)

Comment: @James Kanze, right :) No UB though, `1` would be promoted to `unsigned int` and the overflow would result in `0u`. (Unless, of course, `size_t` is defined as `unsigned char` or `unsigned short`.)

Comment: @avakar i have edited the question.
could you please take a look?

Comment: @avakar No undefined behavior for the addition, no.  Just another example of why using `size_t` everywhere in the standard library was a poor decision.  (Either way, of course, you'll not get an error from `resize`, but the vector won't have the size you want.)

Answer (score 2):

> Also, what would be the size of a pointer to apples object (not asking the size of apples object!)?

I'm sure some language lawyer will come around and point out that this is not correct, but in practice: 32bit builds will use 32 bit pointers, so a pointer to an object is four bytes. In 64bit builds, you get eight bytes per pointer.

Answer (score 2):

It is the size at which, ***if not bound by any resource limits (CPU, memory, time)***, the vector will no longer be able to add any more items to itself.

The amount you can actually store is generally substantially lower due to mainly memory constraints.

The current capacity can be found by calling `vector::capacity()`, and if you'd like to find out how far you can stretch the vector on your current setup, then keep resizing the vector until a `bad_alloc` exception is thrown)

Answer (score 1):

> can i really store 1073741823 pointers in that vector or is this the memory capacity of the vector?

`max_size()` tells you that this implementation of `vector` can't handle a size larger than that; vectors up to that size are possible, *if* there is enough memory available to contain them.

> does the max no of entities store able in a vector depend on the type of entity? if yes, how to calculate that?

That depends on the implementation of both `vector`, and the allocator it uses. In practice it usually will; you'll probably find that it's equal to something like `numeric_limits<size_t>::max() / sizeof (value_type)`; the maximum number of bytes that can be allocated in an array, divided by the object size.

> Also, what would be the size of a pointer to apples object (not asking the size of apples object!)?

That depends on your platform. Since `max_size()` is so small, I'm guessing you're using a 32-bit platform, in which case a pointer will be 32 bits (4 bytes). Other platforms will have different pointer sizes.

Answer (score 0):

hex(1073741823) = '0x3fffffff'

So that looks like some pre-defined limit.

Comment: @CAD_coding I think the other answers have covered this in sufficient detail - basically it's a theoretical maximum, that in practice you'll never be able to reach, due to memory limitations.

Comment: I tried to add more than about a billion elements to a `vector<uint64_t>` today on x64 Ubuntu on a machine which I built a few years ago (it has 12GB ram). Doesn't take that long to fill one up.